# Как объединить два условия if в одно

Tags: c++

Мне нужно объединить два условия if в одно условие.

Код который внизу, полностью рабочий, но он с двумя условиями if

```
if (!(bind(ServSock[i], AI->ai_addr, (int)AI->ai_addrlen) == SOCKET_ERROR
    || SocketType == SOCK_STREAM && listen(ServSock[i], 5) == SOCKET_ERROR))
{
    // пусто
}
else
{
    // второе условия которое надо запихать в первое
    if (i == 0 && AI->ai_next == NULL)
    {
        код 1

        continue;
    }
}

код 2
// прошу заметить код 2 находиться за условием
```

В конце должно получиться что то в этом роде. Как видите даже `else` не будет в коде.

```
if (условие)
{
   код 1
   continue;
}

код 2
```

Comment: не понятно, чего нужно добиться в итоге

Comment: Сделать одно условия if вместо двух

Comment: i++ можно убрать, то есть будет только одна проверка, верно или нет, если верно сработает код 2, если нет сработает код 1 и continue

Comment: «Мне нужно объединить условия, которое должно сработать» — напишите это правильно по-русски, пожалуйста, сейчас непонятно, про одно условие или несколько Вы пишете.

Comment: @IgorRusinov исправил, сделал более упрощенно и вырезал все ненужное.

Comment: Намного практичнее сделать несколько отдельных простых условий, нежели одно громоздкое и сложное. Пройдет неделя, две, месяц, и автор сам перестаёт понимать свой код. Не говоря уже о людях, видящих код впервые.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Достаточно убрать отрицание в начале первого условия и объединить со вторым условием оператором И

```
if (
    (
      bind(ServSock[i], AI->ai_addr, (int)AI->ai_addrlen) == SOCKET_ERROR
      || SocketType == SOCK_STREAM
      && listen(ServSock[i], 5) == SOCKET_ERROR
    )
    && (i == 0 && AI->ai_next == NULL)
   )
{

}
```

но вам в комментариях правильно подсказывают, что лучше разбить на несколько простых условий, это будет понятнее.

Comment: Тут у вас ошибка, надо так     || (i == 0 && AI->ai_next == NULL)

Comment: если будет или, тогда первое условие может быть false, но второе true и тогда это будет не тоже самое, что в первом

Comment: Блин точно, снова запутался значит.

Comment: @zip, "_снова запутался_". Упрощайте. _Отладка кода вдвое сложнее, чем его написание. Так что если вы пишете код настолько умно, насколько можете, то вы по определению недостаточно сообразительны, чтобы его отлаживать.(с)_ Brian W. Kernighan.

Comment: Да я понял надо упрощать код, чет я реально загнул с этими условиями.

Answer (score 3):

Конструкция:

```
if (X) {

}
else {
    if (Y) {
        // do smth
    }
}
```

Эквивалентна:

```
if (!X && Y) {
    // do smth
}
```

Но так как в вашем случае `X` и `Y` это громоздкие выражения, я бы написал:

```
if (!X) {
    if (Y) {
        // do smth
    }
}
```

Или даже, по позможности, зарефакторил это к такому виду:

```
if (X1) {
    return;
}

if (X2) {
    return;
}

if (!Y1) {
    return;
}

if (!Y2) {
    return;
}

//do smth
```

где `Xn` `Yn` простые человекочитаемые выражения.

Comment: Просто если я сделаю как вы показали в последнем варианте у меня будет повторяющий код, можно конечно все в функцию запихать и вызвать функцию, но проще он не станет.

Comment: Я, конечно, не знаю всех деталей, но мне сложно представить код, который после вынесения в отдельную функцию с [guard clauses](https://medium.com/@scadge/if-statements-design-guard-clauses-might-be-all-you-need-67219a1a981a) не станет проще.

Comment: `if (!X) {
    if (Y) {
        // do smth
    }
}
` такой вариант это хорошая мысль, сейчас попробую реализовать.